# Netbeans IDE 7.4 ctrl+space bug

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7.4

My problem is when I'm using ctrl+space on Netbeans my IDE generates my codes with 'ı' character like `voıd` or `publıc` and I have fix with my hand. When I'm coding in Java, when I want to generate getters and setters automatically, Netbeans generates these methods with Turkish characters (replaces the english i with 'ı'), such as `voıd` or `ınt` and `publıc`. How can I fix that bug? Here is part of my trouble:

```
public ınt getAge() {
    return age
}

publıc voıd setAge(ınt age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same was reported as a [bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=157943)

[See if this can help you](https://blogs.oracle.com/tao/entry/set_netbeans_user_interface_language)

Which says :

Netbeans automatically uses the Windows system default language as the default user interface language. I believe that it means to be a nice feature for localization. But I personally find it uncomfortable because I have been used with English interface.

After I did some Google search, I learned a few tips to set the Netbeans UI language.

> 1. Temporary Solution
>
>    Add "--locale en:US" at the end of Netbeans startup command.
>
>    "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.0.1\bin\netbeans.exe"  --locale en:US
> 2. Permanent Solution
>
>    Go to Netbeans installation directory, for example,
>
>    C:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.0.1\etc
>
>    Open "netbeans.conf" and find netbeans default option line
>
>    netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m -J-Xverify:none -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true"
>
>    Add "-J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US" to the end of this line
>
>    netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m -J-Xverify:none -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US"

Comment: This is a comment. Not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with foreign languages. I have faced this since I'm also from Turkey. Here is how to fix it:

Go to the *NetBeans IDE install directory*. Go to the folder `etc` and open `netbeans.conf` with a text editing program such as *Notepad* or *Notepad++*. Then find `netbeans_default_options=`, preferably with **CTRL+F** and add `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the existing values. After that, just save and reload *Netbeans IDE*.

Comment: sorry about it i can't upvote for my reputation point. I have only 6 point and i cant upvote :(

Comment: @enginear It's OK. Glad I could help :P